# Replace ' with \' for some reason puts \\'

Tags: c#

I have the following code which worked fine up to today:

```
string aName = dr["Name"].ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aName))
    aName = aName.Replace("'", @"\'");
```

For some reason it's replacing `"Dominic's  - CA"` with `"Dominic\\'s  - CA"`

This link shows exactly what the raw data looks like in the database

[image: raw data]

Any ideas on how the 2 backslashes are appearing?

Comment: The debugger has a text visualizer.  Click the spyglass icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any ideas on how the 2 backslashes are appearing?

Yes. You're almost certainly looking at the string in the debugger. The actual string only has a single backslash. Log it, write it out to the console, display it in a form or whatever and you'll see that there's only one backslash.

Unfortunately the debugger "helpfully" escapes backslashes for you, giving you text which could appear as a string literal in C#. This has tripped up countless people, and I'm going to ask the VS team to try to either make it more obvious or do *something* to improve the situation...

Comment: (The "Text View" of the value should not have the extra slash - there should be an icon on the right of the value to open the view.)

Comment: @user2864740: Thanks for that. Though by the time you know to look there, you probably know what to look for anyway ;)